# Rails app with another browser string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a question about browser string in rails.

For example i have rails app with routes:

```
resources :posts
```

and this resource create :

```
post/:id

post/21
post/167
post/356
```

but i create a simple blog and i want to rename ':id' to

```
post/some-name
post/another-name
post/another-different-name
```

in post i have title, text field 
but i dont know how do this

I know that this can be achieved through manipulation of the :id

can you post some link with detailed answer on this question, or some simple example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course put anything you want in the URL and actually there is railcast about it:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url

It is preferable (read: easier) to also keep model.id in the URL, or it means that post name MUST be unique, otherwise you can put anything you want:

```
/post/2465-my-pretty-post-name
```

Also, there is a gem [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) and related railcast:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes! this is what I wanted - even more. thn!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to change /post/:id ? 
You can achieve something like /post/:id/comments

You can do that using nested resources like this in your routes.rb

resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end

Check here for more details
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: No, i want like railscasts brawser string -> http://railscasts.com/episodes/223-charts-graphs-revised , but i can release only "../episodes/223" - how can i add "-charts-graphs-revised" to browser string in id ?

Comment: I suggest you do episode/223/charts-graphs-revised . Else you can just add a single route to routes.rb like get epsiode/223-charts-graphs-revised. I don't think you would be able to acheive something like 223-xyz , 224-xyz and moreover it does make much sense to build such urls.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the to_param method to the model then you can use that within your URL system.

```
class SomeModel < ...

  def to_param
    self.title
  end

end
```

Then inside your controller, setup a filter to fetch the model using the title attribute instead of the ID attribute which is used for the find method.

```
before_filter :setup_record

def setup_record
  @record ||= Record.find_by_title(params[:id])
end
```

You will have to ensure that your title stays unique and if you change it then you will either have to discard all other previous URLS or keep a history of older names.